# send multivariables to ubidots with the nodemcu esp8266?

Tags: esp8266

I have a project regarding health monitoring, I used NodeMCU esp8266 device and ad8232 for ecg and also max30102 for spo2 and bpmI wanted to display these three variables on ubidots using wifi but the platform says there is no information “no found information” , If you have only one variable, ecg for example, the platform responds and displays the chart. But it does not respond if I want to work with the three variables. please help if the error is in the code.
this is the code for declare variables:

```
#define DEVICE_LABEL "monitoring" // Put the device label
#define VARIABLE_LABEL_1 "ecgmoy" // Put the variable label
#define VARIABLE_LABEL_2 "spo2" // Put the variable label
#define VARIABLE_LABEL_3 "heartRate" // Put the variable label
```

and for send and display :

```
       dtostrf(ecgmoy, 4, 2, str_val_1);
       dtostrf(spo2, 4, 2, str_val_2);
       dtostrf(heartRate, 4, 2, str_val_3);
    sprintf(topic, "%s", ""); // Cleans the topic content
    sprintf(topic, "%s%s", "/v1.6/devices/", DEVICE_LABEL); 
    sprintf(payload, "%s", ""); // Cleans the payload content
     sprintf(payload, "{\"%s\":", VARIABLE_LABEL_1); // Adds the variable label
    sprintf(payload, "%s {\"value\": %s}", payload, str_val_1); // Adds the value
    sprintf(payload, "{\"%s\":", VARIABLE_LABEL_2); // Adds the variable label
   sprintf(payload, "%s {\"value\": %s}", payload, str_val_2); // Adds the value
   sprintf(payload, "%s, \"%s\":", payload, VARIABLE_LABEL_3); // Adds the variable label
   sprintf(payload, "%s {\"value\": %s}", payload, str_val_3); // Adds the value
    sprintf(payload, "%s}", payload); // Closes the dictionary brackets
    Serial.println("Publishing data to Ubidots Cloud");
    client.publish(topic, payload);
    client.loop();  
    delay(10);   
    }
```

please help !

Comment: Whatever error that occured, it is not in the part of the code that you shown. Debugging rule #1, read the error message, at which line of code that the error occured. If you need help, show us the code where the error occured and how you declare and use the variable(s)? not the code that has nothing to do with the error.

Comment: thanks for your answer sir @hcheung . When I execute there is no error occured, for the code this is it in the following answer :

Comment: With the post of complete code, it help to understand what you means about the problem that you are facing. However, please don't post the problematic code as an "answer", you should click on the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69483265/send-multivariables-to-ubidots-with-the-nodemcu-esp8266/69512476#69512476) to add new update...

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>
#include "MAX30105.h"
#include "spo2_algorithm.h"

#define WIFISSID "W055" // Put your Wifi SSID here
#define PASSWORD "123456789" // Put your WIFI password here
#define TOKEN "BBFF-9y3LaMBjvWcslJB1qRCLWwUku8YxED" // Put your Ubidots' TOKEN
#define DEVICE_LABEL "monitoring" // Put the device label
#define VARIABLE_LABEL_1 "ecgmoy" // Put the variable label
#define VARIABLE_LABEL_2 "spo2" // Put the variable label
#define VARIABLE_LABEL_3 "heartRate" // Put the variable label


#define MQTT_CLIENT_NAME "myecgsensor" // MQTT client Name, please enter your own 8-12 alphanumeric character ASCII string; 
                                           //it should be a random and unique ascii string and different from all other devices
 
/****************************************
* Define Constants
****************************************/
#define output A0 // Set the A0 as output
const int N=10;      // Définition du nombre d'échantillons
int ecg[N];          // un tableau pour stocker les échantillons lus
int n= 0;       // l'indice de l'échantillon courant
float ecgmoy =0 ;    // la moyenne des échantillons mémorisés
float somme =0;   // la somme des échantillons mémorisés
//........SpO2........//
MAX30105 particleSensor;
uint32_t irBuffer[100]; //infrared LED sensor data
uint32_t redBuffer[100];  //red LED sensor data
int32_t bufferLength; //data length
int32_t spo2; //SPO2 value
int8_t validSPO2; //indicator to show if the SPO2 calculation is valid
int32_t heartRate; //heart rate value
int8_t validHeartRate; //indicator to show if the heart rate calculation is valid


char mqttBroker[] = "industrial.api.ubidots.com";
char payload[100];
char topic[150];

// Space to store values to send
char str_val_1[10];
char str_val_2[10];
char str_val_3[10];
 
/****************************************
* Auxiliar Functions
****************************************/
WiFiClient ubidots;
PubSubClient client(ubidots);
void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) {
  char p[length + 1];
  memcpy(p, payload, length);
  p[length] = NULL;
  Serial.write(payload, length);
  Serial.println(topic);
}
void reconnect() {
  // Loop until we're reconnected
  while (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.println("Attempting MQTT connection...");    
    // Attemp to connect
    if (client.connect(MQTT_CLIENT_NAME, TOKEN, "")) {
      Serial.println("Connected");
    } else {
      Serial.print("Failed, rc=");
      Serial.print(client.state());
      Serial.println(" try again in 2 seconds");
      // Wait 2 seconds before retrying
      delay(2000);
    }
  }
}
 
/****************************************
* Main Functions
****************************************/
void setup() {

  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.begin(WIFISSID, PASSWORD);
   Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Waiting for WiFi..."); 
  while (WiFi.status()  != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(500);
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi Connected");
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  client.setServer(mqttBroker, 1883);
  client.setCallback(callback); 

   // Assign the pin as INPUT 
  pinMode(output, INPUT); 
    /************************/
  
   /*************************/
  
 pinMode  (LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
 Serial.print("Initializing pulse oximeter..");
 if (!particleSensor.begin(Wire, I2C_SPEED_FAST)) //Use default I2C port, 400kHz speed
  {
    Serial.println(F("MAX30102 was not found. Please check wiring/power."));
    while (1);
  }

  Serial.println(F("Attach sensor to finger with rubber band. Press any key to start conversion"));
  while (Serial.available() == 0) ; //wait until user presses a key
  Serial.read();

  byte ledBrightness = 60; //Options: 0=Off to 255=50mA
  byte sampleAverage = 4; //Options: 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32
  byte ledMode = 2; //Options: 1 = Red only, 2 = Red + IR, 3 = Red + IR + Green
  byte sampleRate = 100; //Options: 50, 100, 200, 400, 800, 1000, 1600, 3200
  int pulseWidth = 411; //Options: 69, 118, 215, 411
  int adcRange = 4096; //Options: 2048, 4096, 8192, 16384
 particleSensor.setup(ledBrightness, sampleAverage, ledMode, sampleRate, pulseWidth, adcRange); //Configure sensor with these settings

  for (int i=0 ; i<N ; i++)
  { 
    ecg [i] = 0; 
    }
}

void loop() {
  if (!client.connected()) 
  {  reconnect(); }
 Serial.begin (115200);
    /******spo2********/
 bufferLength = 100; //buffer length of 100 stores 4 seconds of samples running at 25sps
  //read the first 100 samples, and determine the signal range
  for (byte i = 0 ; i < bufferLength ; i++)
  {  
    while (particleSensor.available() == false) //do we have new data?
      particleSensor.check(); //Check the sensor for new data
    redBuffer[i] = particleSensor.getRed();
    irBuffer[i] = particleSensor.getIR();
    particleSensor.nextSample(); //We're finished with this sample so move to next sample  
    }
//calculate heart rate and SpO2 after first 100 samples (first 4 seconds of samples)
  maxim_heart_rate_and_oxygen_saturation(irBuffer, bufferLength, redBuffer, &spo2, &validSPO2, &heartRate, &validHeartRate);
  //Continuously taking samples from MAX30102.  Heart rate and SpO2 are calculated every 1 second
  while (1)  {
    //dumping the first 25 sets of samples in the memory and shift the last 75 sets of samples to the top
    for (byte i = 25; i < 100; i++)   {   redBuffer[i - 25] = redBuffer[i];
                                          irBuffer[i - 25] = irBuffer[i];   }
    //take 25 sets of samples before calculating the heart rate.
    for (byte i = 75; i < 100; i++)
    {     
      while (particleSensor.available() == false) //do we have new data?
        particleSensor.check(); //Check the sensor for new data

      redBuffer[i] = particleSensor.getRed();
      irBuffer[i] = particleSensor.getIR();
      particleSensor.nextSample(); //We're finished with this sample so move to next sample

      //send samples and calculation result to terminal program through UART
      Serial.print(F("red="));
      Serial.print(redBuffer[i], DEC);
      Serial.print(F(", ir="));
      Serial.print(irBuffer[i], DEC);

      Serial.print(F(", HR="));
      Serial.print(heartRate, DEC);

      Serial.print(F(", HRvalid="));
      Serial.print(validHeartRate, DEC);

      Serial.print(F(", SPO2="));
      Serial.print(spo2, DEC);

      Serial.print(F(", SPO2Valid="));
      Serial.println(validSPO2, DEC);
    }

    //After gathering 25 new samples recalculate HR and SP02
    maxim_heart_rate_and_oxygen_saturation(irBuffer, bufferLength, redBuffer, &spo2, &validSPO2, &heartRate, &validHeartRate);
  }
   /*******ecg*******/
  somme = somme - ecg [n];
     // Lecture du capteur
      ecg[n] = analogRead(output);
     Serial.print(ecg [n]);
     // Ajout du dernier echantillon
     somme = somme + ecg [n];
    // Incrémentation de n
     n++;
     if (n>= N){
      // ...retour au début
     n =0; }
     ecgmoy = somme / N;
     //delay(20);
     
       dtostrf(ecgmoy, 4, 2, str_val_1);
       dtostrf(spo2, 4, 2, str_val_2);
       dtostrf(heartRate, 4, 2, str_val_3);
    sprintf(topic, "%s", ""); // Cleans the topic content
    sprintf(topic, "%s%s", "/v1.6/devices/", DEVICE_LABEL); 
    sprintf(payload, "%s", ""); // Cleans the payload content
     sprintf(payload, "{\"%s\":", VARIABLE_LABEL_1); // Adds the variable label
    sprintf(payload, "%s {\"value\": %s}", payload, str_val_1); // Adds the value
    sprintf(payload, "{\"%s\":", VARIABLE_LABEL_2); // Adds the variable label
   sprintf(payload, "%s {\"value\": %s}", payload, str_val_2); // Adds the value
   sprintf(payload, "%s, \"%s\":", payload, VARIABLE_LABEL_3); // Adds the variable label
   sprintf(payload, "%s {\"value\": %s}", payload, str_val_3); // Adds the value
    sprintf(payload, "%s}", payload); // Closes the dictionary brackets
    Serial.println("Publishing data to Ubidots Cloud");
    client.publish(topic, payload);
    client.loop();  
    delay(10);   
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For this part of the code:

```
   sprintf(payload, "%s", ""); // Cleans the payload content
   sprintf(payload, "{\"%s\":", VARIABLE_LABEL_1); // Adds the variable label
   sprintf(payload, "%s {\"value\": %s}", payload, str_val_1); // Adds the value
   sprintf(payload, "{\"%s\":", VARIABLE_LABEL_2); // Adds the variable label
   sprintf(payload, "%s {\"value\": %s}", payload, str_val_2); // Adds the value
   sprintf(payload, "%s, \"%s\":", payload, VARIABLE_LABEL_3); // Adds the variable label
   sprintf(payload, "%s {\"value\": %s}", payload, str_val_3); // Adds the value
   sprintf(payload, "%s}", payload); // Closes the dictionary brackets
```

If you printout the `payload`, you will notice that `ecgmoy` is missing and shows as

```
{"spo2": {"value": xx.xx}, "heartRate": {"value": yy.yy}}
```

This is caused by the `sprintf` that override the previous value of `payload`, Your code is over-declared with variables/macro that are not necessary, making it difficult to follow and debug. Many variables are not necessary to be declared as global variables, it is better to declare at where you use it.

You code can be simplified as two lines of code

```
char payload[100]={'\0'}; // declare and initialised with '\0'
sprintf(payload, 
  "{\"ecgmoy\": {\"value\": %s}, {\"spo2\": {\"value\": %s}, \"heartRate\": {\"value\": %s}}", 
  str_val_1, 
  str_val_2, 
  str_val_3
);
```